# How to use NSSortDescriptor to sort an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssortdescriptor

I'm using the following NSSortDescriptor code to sort an array. I'm currently sorting by price but would like to also put a limit on the price. Is it possible to sort by price but only show price less than 100 for example?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey: @"price" ascending: YES];

NSMutableArray *sortedArray = (NSMutableArray *)[self.displayItems
                                                     sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

[self setDisplayItems:sortedArray];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: You can't just cast an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray`. Use `[array mutableCopy]`

Comment: Sebastian is right. An NSArray will always be an NSArray for as long as it lives, unless it is a member of a subclass, in which case, it will always be a member of that subclass.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not quite enough to only sort the array - you need to filter it as well.

If we maintain the structure of your original code, you can add a filter like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey: @"price" ascending: YES];

NSArray *sortedArray = [self.displayItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"price < 100"];
NSMutableArray *filteredAndSortedArray = [sortedArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: pred];

[self setDisplayItems: [filteredAndSortedArray mutableCopy]];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

If performance becomes an issue, you might want to inverse the filtering and the sorting, but that's a detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter the array with specified range in price, then sort the filtered array & display the sorted array in tableview !!!

For filtering you can use `NSPredicate` & for sorting you can use the same `NSSortDescriptor`

Hope this helps you !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"your key" ascending:true];
[yourarray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];
[sorter release];
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't that the same thing that I have? I need to not only sort price (my key) but also only show price if it's <= 100 etc...

Comment: Why downvote? NSSortDescriptor is just for sorting your array. If you want to set the limit for price, then go with NSPredicate.

Comment: @Sebastian as per the question, I had given ans for sorting the array using NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: But the question was **Is it possible to sort by price but only show price less than 100 for example?**

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray * weekDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *dictArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [weekDays count]; i++)
{
    dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i],@"WeekDay",[weekDays objectAtIndex:i],@"Name",nil];
    [dictArray addObject:dict];
}
NSLog(@"Before Sorting : %@",dictArray);

@try
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *descriptor = @[sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [dictArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
    NSLog(@"After Sorting : %@",sortedArray);
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorting cant be done because of some error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",exception] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert setTag:500];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```